# Sorting function for non commuting bosons

Tags: sorting

I am trying to write a sorting function which will sort expressions involving products of bosonic objects which do not commute. For example, I can have objects like $a,\ a^\dagger,\ b,\ b^\dagger$ where $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$, $[b,b^\dagger] = 1$ and all other commutators vanish. So the sorting function should for example sort a term like $a a^\dagger b a b^\dagger$ to $a + a^\dagger a^2 + ab^\dagger b+a^\dagger a^2 b^\dagger b$. So I want to sort them first lexicographically and then such that dagger objects will be to the left.

I have been using a function from the notebook provided by Simon Tyler at [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/src/1102.3043v2/anc/GoldstinoCode.nb). So I have created a bosonic object using

```
Clear[Boson, BosonC, BosonA]
Boson /: MakeBoxes[
 Boson[cr : (True | False), sym_], fmt_] := 
  With[{sbox = If[StringQ[sym], sym, ToBoxes[sym]]}, 
   With[{abox = If[cr, SuperscriptBox[#, FormBox["\[Dagger]", Bold]], #] &@sbox},
    InterpretationBox[abox, Boson[cr, sym]]
   ]
  ]
BosonA[sym_:"a"] := Boson[False, sym]
BosonC[sym_:"a"] := Boson[True, sym]
```

Next following the code, I want to turn the atomic expressions into lists and use Mathematica's ordering after that. So I have functions like

```
NCOrder[Boson[cr : True | False, sym_]] := 
NCOrder[Boson[cr, sym]] = {{sym, Boole[cr]}}

NCSort[expr_] := Module[{temp, NCM},
 temp = expr /. NonCommutativeMultiply -> NCM;   
 temp = temp /. (NCM[a : _Boson ..] :> (NCM[a][[Ordering[#]]] &[NCOrder /@ {a}]));
 temp = temp /. NCM[singleArg_] :> singleArg;   
 temp = temp /. NCM -> NonCommutativeMultiply
]
```

This NCSort function right now is just ordering it lexicographically. I want to modify it so that it would sort and order the expressions as I explained above.

Comment: Ordering of creation/annihilation operators isn't a sort in a traditional sense as you are not just rearranging terms, but modifying them in the process. Most sorting assumes a stable length, and this process does not have that.

Comment: See section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation" in [this nb](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/). It has a couple of examples that use commutators and do canonicalization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest the following function, which looks rather ugly and is not really efficient, but seems to do the job:

```
expand[expr_] :=
 Module[{times},
   expr /.
     NonCommutativeMultiply[b___] :> times[b] //.
     {
       times[left___, cnum_ /; FreeQ[cnum, _Boson], right___] :> 
             cnum*times[left, right],
       times[left___, fst : Boson[_, s_], middle__, sec : Boson[_, s_],right___] /;
          FreeQ[{middle}, Boson[_, s]] &&
              OrderedQ[{Last@Union[Cases[{middle}, Boson[_, sym_] :> sym]], s}] :>
                  times[left, middle, fst, sec, right],
       times[left___, Boson[False, s_], Boson[True, s_], right___] :>
          times[left, right] + times[left, Boson[True, s], Boson[False, s], right],
       times[b_Boson] :> b
     } //.
    times[left___, p : Longest[PatternSequence[(b : Boson[type_, s_]) ..]],right___] :>
      times[left, b^Length[{p}], right] /. 
    times[arg__] :> NonCommutativeMultiply[arg] /. times[] -> OverHat[1]
];
```

You can use it as

```
expand[NonCommutativeMultiply[BosonA["a"], BosonC["a"], BosonA["b"], BosonA["a"], BosonC["b"]]]

(*
    a+a^\[Dagger]**a^2+a**b^\[Dagger]**b+a^\[Dagger]**a^2**b^\[Dagger]**b
*)
```

Comment: @Jens Works for me `expand[NonCommutativeMultiply[BosonA["a"],BosonC["a"]]]` gives `NonCommutativeMultiply[]+a^\[Dagger]**a`

Comment: @Jens Right, I forgot to mention - should be `If` instead of `f`. I corrected it in the post.

Comment: Thanks - I just saw that it had already been edited but I must have had the old definition. Miscommunication.

Comment: @Jens No, I edited already after your comment on this, so you could not have used the edited version when you tried.

Comment: Good, so I was only half blind. Anyway, I already gave you +1 and I've tested some more, also combining with `Plus`, without finding anything wrong.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for testing and an upvote, good to know that it works. It basically does what we usually do by hand. But, if you ask me, it is esier to switch to path integrals, no operators - no problems :) (I am joking - operator formalism  certainly has its merits)

Comment: @Leonid I just saw this and I am still trying to understand the code but I tried it and it works great for the example that I mentioned however I tried another example like `a**a**a^\dagger**a^\dagger` which should expand to `2 + 4 a^\dagger**a + a^\dagger**a^\dagger*a*a` but it doesn't expand anything.

Comment: @Karan Your example does expand exactly as expected for me.

Comment: @Karan Works for me too: `expand[NonCommutativeMultiply[BosonA["a"], BosonA["a"], BosonC["a"], BosonC["a"]]]` results in `2 NonCommutativeMultiply[] +  4 Boson[True, "a"] ** Boson[False, "a"] + (Boson[True, "a"])^2 ** Boson[False, "a"]^2`. Make sure you use the corrected definitions for the boson operator formatting: I edited your post, since you had `f` instead of `If` in one place.

Comment: Leonid, here's a suggestion for improvement: how about replacing the last rule in your `expand` module by `times[arg__] :> NonCommutativeMultiply[arg] /. times[] -> OverHat[1]` so that the identity operator is displayed in a more readable form?

Comment: It works now. I had modified the properties of NonCommutativeMultiply in my original notebook to make it distributive and other things which I believe was conflicting somehow with `expand`.

Comment: @Jens Thanks, edited.

Comment: So I ran into a trouble. The expressions I need to simplify contain c-numbers in front of the oscillators. The function expand will only simplify if the input arguments are purely Boson objects. Is there to modify the function so that it will factor out the c-numbers and then expand?

Comment: @Karan See the edited version. Try to understand the logic here, this part with c-numbers was not hard at all.

Comment: @Leonid I tried to use this `times[left___, Times[n_?NumericQ, b : Boson[type_, s_]], right___] :>  n*times[left, b, right]`. Can you tell me what is wrong with this line?

Comment: @Leonid Also the edited version evaluates `a**2**b` to `2 a**b` but not `a**(2*b)`.

Comment: @Karan I don't have much time now, but `Times` sometimes evaluates, so you often need `HoldPattern`. I also did not include `Times` in the rule, that's why your input does not evaluate.

Comment: @Leonid I appended this line in the function `times[left___, cnum_ /; (! FreeQ[cnum, Times[n_?NumericQ, _Boson]]), 
  right___] :> Extract[FactorList[cnum], {1, 1}]*times[left,Extract[FactorList[cnum], {2, 1}], right]` and it does the job however there are some other issues. When I have fractions, it doesn't work. Also the function isn't distributive over addition. I tried a similar command but that is not very general.

Comment: @Karan Good that you managed. In general, such problems are expected. If you want to make it rather general-purpose, you have to add more rules.