# Boson commutation relations

Tags: physics, algebra

I have tried to adapt [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16290/29734) to my problem of calculating some bosonic commutation relations, but there are still some issues.

The way I'm implementing the commutator is straightforward:

```
commutator[x_, y_] :=x**y-y**x
```

Example: if I want to compute $[b^\dagger b,ab^\dagger]$ I write

```
commutator[BosonC["b"]**BosonA["b"], BosonA["a"]**BosonC["b"]]
```

and the output is $ab^\dagger$ as it should be.
However this fails when I compute $[a^\dagger a,ab^\dagger]$ (which should be $-ab^\dagger)$:

```
commutator[BosonC["a"]**BosonA["a"], BosonA["a"]**BosonC["b"]]
 Out: a†** a^2 ** b†- a ** b†** a†** a
```

How can I modify the code [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16290/29734) to have it work properly?

**EDIT**
Building on the answers of @QuantumDot and @evanb, I came up with this solution. First I implement the commutator, with `Distribute`.

```
NCM[x___] = NonCommutativeMultiply[x];
SetAttributes[commutator, HoldAll]

NCM[] := 1
commutator[NCM[x___], NCM[y___]] := Distribute[NCM[x, y] - NCM[y, x]]
commutator[x_, y_] := Distribute[NCM[x, y] - NCM[y, x]]
```

Then I implement two tools, one for teaching Mathematica how to swap creation and annihilation operators and one is for operator ordering:

```
dag[x_] := ToExpression[ToString[x] ~~ "†"]

mode[x_] := With[{x†= dag[x]},
NCM[left___, x, x†, right___] := NCM[left, x†, x, right] + NCM[left, right]]

leftright[L_, R_] := With[{R† = dag[R], L† = dag[L]}, 
NCM[left___, pr : R | R†, pl : L | L†, right___] := NCM[left, pl, pr, right]]
```

Now I can use it like this: after evaluating the definitions I input (for instance)

```
mode[a]
mode[b]
leftright[a,b]
```

And finally I can evaluate commutators, for instance

```
commutator[NCM[a†,a] + NCM[b†,b], NCM[a,b†]]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Can you write out the reasoning behind $[a^{\dagger} a, a b^{\dagger}] = -a b^{\dagger}$? It's not clear what rules you apply to get that, from this question or the linked one.

Comment: The dagger is `\[Dagger]` or `<escape> dg <escape>`

Comment: Can you post the full code that actually produces `a ** b\[Dagger]` from `commutator[BosonC["b"]**BosonA["b"], BosonA["a"]**BosonC["b"]]`?

Comment: @PatrickStevens. See the relations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Creation_and_annihilation_operators_in_quantum_field_theories): bosons (not fermions).

Comment: perhaps you would like to have a look at SNEG package :) http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/

Comment: Hard to say much without full code to replicate the behavior.

Comment: To be clear: is the lexicographic ordering of that question that you linked to important. That is, are you just using that code to get things in normal order, or do you care about the fact that, say, `a`'s should be to the left of `b`'s?

Comment: @march I'd like the a's to commute with the b's, which seems to happen (at least internally in the code) in the first example, but now in the second. The code I'm using is exactly the one in Leonid's answer in the link.

Comment: No, I understand that the `a`'s and `b`'s commute (it's a boson algebra, after all). I was wondering whether the lexicographical ordering was important for you (i.e. putting the `a`'s to the left of the `b`'s), or if the normal-ordering was all that mattered, or perhaps the grouping + normal ordering matters, but not the lexicographical ordering, etc.

Comment: @march oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. Well, no, I don't value the lexicographical order particularly, I just would like to get to the simplest form possible. I'm aware that "simplest" is kind of an undefined term, but I typically trust MMA's take on it...

Comment: I understand this is an old question, but I am working on something related to this. Your code seems to work for the basic examples, but could you see a way for it to also work with exponential operators? As in, $e^{i a^\dagger a}$ for example. Because the way I see it that is not possible right now, is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `NonCommutativeMultiply` has too long of a name, so I make a short-hand version of it (`NCP` stands for **n**on-**c**ommutative **p**roduct):

```
NCP[x___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[x];
```

Now, here's the code

```
NCP[] := 1
NCP[left___, a, a†, right___] := NCP[left, a†, a, right] + NCP[left, right]
NCP[left___, b, b†, right___] := NCP[left, b†, b, right] + NCP[left, right]
NCP[left___, pl : a | a†, pr : b | b†, right___] := NCP[left, pr, pl, right]
```

Now your function:

```
SetAttributes[commutator, HoldAll]    
commutator[NCP[x___], NCP[y___]] := NCP[x, y] - NCP[y, x]
```

Let's give it a try:

```
commutator[NCP[b†, b], NCP[a, b†]]
```

> `b† ** a`

Comment: Great answer too, I'm testing them out. Here I would need linearity to make it perfect. Maybe I can fiddle around with `Distribute`

Answer (score 10):

You get get far by just implementing the linearity rules for the commutator (and that 0 and 1 "escape" the matrix product.  The first two aren't strictly needed, but I include them for completeness:

```
commutator[Plus[a_,A__],B_]:=commutator[a,B]+commutator[Plus[A],B]
commutator[A_,Plus[b_,B__]]:=commutator[A,b]+commutator[A,Plus[B]]
commutator[A_**B_,C_]:=A**commutator[B,C]+commutator[A,C]**B
commutator[A_,B_**C_]:=B**commutator[A,C]+commutator[A,B]**C
commutator[A_,A_]:=0
commutator[___,0,___]:=0

Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[___,0,___]:=0
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, 1, T___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[H, T]
```

Now evaluating `commutator[adag**a,a**bdag]` gives

```
(a**commutator[adag,bdag]+commutator[adag,a]**bdag)**a+adag**a**commutator[a,bdag]
```

You can get further by implementing the fact that different oscillators commute.  For example:

```
commutator[adag, bdag] = 0
commutator[a, bdag] = 0
```

Reevaluating `commutator[adag**a,a**bdag]` gives

```
commutator[adag, a] ** bdag ** a
```

Finally, you can implement the canonical relation:

```
commutator[adag, a] = 1;
```

To get what you want.

You can of course decorate / generalize what's above so that you don't have to write every relation out by hand.

Comment: This is great! How can I tell MMA that the commutator is antisymmetric (so I can avoid writing the rules for, say, both [a,a†] and [a†,a], etc..?)

Comment: Ah, that's a little bit tricky.  You have to make sure you don't create a pattern that always binds, giving an infinite loop.  One simple solution is `commutator[A_, B_] := -commutator[B, A] /; Not[OrderedQ[{A, B}]]`.  You can come up with more complicated predicates if you want particular orderings, of course.  The above works, for example, if you specify [a,adag]=-1, but it won't deduce that relation from [adag, a]=1.

Comment: Another approach is to use `Simplify` with a custom `TransformationFunction`.  Assuming the definitions in my answer:

`tryOtherOrder[e_] := (e /. {commutator[A_, B_] :> -commutator[B, A]})`
`commutator[a, adag] (* doesn't change *)`
`Simplify[commutator[a, adag], TransformationFunctions -> tryOtherOrder] (* gives -1*)`