# Normal ordering in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, algebra, canonicalization

I want to create a function which normally orders a string of field operators. Consider the following:

$$\langle0\vert\hat{a}(k_n) \cdots \hat{a}(k_2)\hat{a}(k_1)\hat{a}^\dagger(k_1)\hat{a}^\dagger(k_2) \cdots \hat{a}^\dagger(k_n)\vert 0\rangle.$$

I would like to write the expression in the brackets with all daggered operators on the left, with the field operators satisfying

$$\left[\hat{a}(k_i), \hat{a}^\dagger(k_j)\right] = \delta(k_i - k_j),$$
$$\left[\hat{a}(k_i), \hat{a}(k_j)\right] = \left[\hat{a}^\dagger(k_i), \hat{a}^\dagger(k_j)\right] = 0.$$

This will generate many terms and I would like Mathematica to generate the terms for any specified $n$.

The required non-commutativity of the operators has been addressed in this post; [Boson commutation relations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95616/boson-commutation-relations/95716#95716), but I am stuck in using it to achieve a normally ordered expression.

Comment: You might be interested in SNEG library (http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/). It is a mathematica package for second quantization. I think it does what you are looking for.

Comment: SNEG library does not work well at all for $n$ larger than 3. I need to take $n$ to much larger values

Comment: I was going to link to my answer of that other question, but it seems you already knew about it!  Magic!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Represent a string of field operators `a[k]`$\equiv\hat{a}(k)$ and `ad[k]`$\equiv\hat{a}^\dagger(k)$sandwiched between the ground state as `correlate`.

Then the definitions that will automate the manipulations is as follows:

```
ClearAll[correlate];

(*  Normalization <0|0> = 1  *)
correlate[] = 1;


(*  Commutation relation: [a(k1), a†(k2)] = δ(k1-k2)  *)
correlate[left___, a[k1_], ad[k2_], right___] :=
  correlate[left, ad[k2], a[k1], right] + δ[k1 - k2] correlate[left, right];


(*  Commutation relations: [a(k1), a(k2)] = [a†(k1), a†(k2)] = 0  *)
correlate[left___, a[k1_], a[k2_], right___] /; !OrderedQ[{k2, k1}] := 
  correlate[left, a[k2], a[k1], right];

correlate[left___, ad[k1_], ad[k2_], right___] /; !OrderedQ[{k2, k1}] := 
  correlate[left, ad[k2], ad[k1], right];


(*  Annihilation of vacuum state: <0|a† and a|0> = 0  *)
correlate[___, a[_]] := 0;
correlate[ad[_], ___] := 0;
```

Here's a test:

```
correlate[a[k10], a[k9], ad[k8], a[k7], ad[k6], a[k5], ad[k4], ad[k3]]
```

> [image]

Comment: this works great for the string asked in the question. Can an extension of correlate handle cases where some field operators in the string appear multiple times? At the moment, the above doesn't handle repeats.

Comment: @Sid I'm sure I can.  But to help me out, would you give me a couple examples and their expected results?

Comment: Actually there is a bug in my code.  Instead of `OrderedQ`, I should have `!OrderedQ`.  I'm fixing it now.  Try the new version, and let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll just chime in and say you might want to use `δ[k1,k2]` rather than `δ[k1-k2]` depending on whether your momentum space is continuous or not.  I suppose you can always make replacements.

Comment: `OrderedQ` and `!OrderedQ` seem to achieve the same result. But it still doesn't work if I have two of the same creation operators. I.e. for example `correlate[a[k10], a[k9], ad[k8], a[k7], ad[k6], a[k5], ad[k4], 
   ad[k4]]`

Comment: @Sid Be sure to clear definitions with `ClearAll[correlate]` after making the change to `!OrderedQ` to eliminate the old (buggy) definition from memory.  (Or rerun from a fresh kernel).  Your example works on my machine.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you kindly!