# How to implement ladder operators for the quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: physics, algebra

I would like to write the annihilation and creation operators for the harmonic oscillator, and see how they act on basis states of the form $\lvert n\rangle$.

What's the best approach to implement this in Mathematica?

In particular, this would require to implement the commutation relations $[a,a^\dagger] =  1$, and to see how $|n\rangle$ changes when we apply the creation and destruction operators $a^\dagger$ and $a$.

Comment: for how to implement the commutation rules on bosonic operators see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95714/27539)

Comment: Do you need the operators for general non-commutative algebra, or do you just need matrix representations in some finite basis for calculating expectation values?  If the latter, it's fairly straightforward

Comment: @JasonB. I am trying to get the algebric form, namely not the matrix.

Comment: There is the [quantum package](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/quantum/) that has an example of harmonic oscillator.

Comment: @JasonB. you're right, if it is a finite basis of dimension, `k`, it is simple: `a[k_] := DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, k-1], k, -1]` and $a^\dagger$ is then automatically defined.

Comment: @rcollyer I think the correct function for annihilation is: `a[k_] := DiagonalMatrix[Sqrt /@ Range[1, k - 1], 1, k]`.

Comment: @SaurabhShringarpure probably. It's been years since I've looked at this, though, so I couldn't give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
Protect[qCO, qDO];

qOperatorQ[expr_] := MatchQ[expr, qCO | qDO | Ket[n_Integer]];

(* take scalars out *)
CenterDot[left___, Times[scalar_?NumericQ, op_?qOperatorQ], right___] := Times[
    scalar,
    CenterDot[left, op, right]
  ];

(* Implement commutation relations *)
CenterDot[left___, qDO, qCO, right___] := Plus[
    CenterDot[left, qCO, qDO, right],
    CenterDot[left, right]
  ];

(* Allow to use powers of operators *)
CenterDot[left___, Power[op : (qCO | qDO), n_Integer], right___] := CenterDot[
    left,
    Sequence @@ ConstantArray[op, n],
    right
  ];

(* effective OneIdentity attribute *)
CenterDot[op_?qOperatorQ] := op;

(* implement action on Fock states *)
CenterDot[left___, qDO, Ket[0]] := 0;
CenterDot[left___, qCO, Ket[n_Integer]] := Times[
    Sqrt[n + 1],
    CenterDot[left, Ket[n + 1]]
  ];
CenterDot[left___, qDO, Ket[n_Integer]] := Times[
    Sqrt[n],
    CenterDot[left, Ket[n - 1]]
  ];
```

I used `CenterDot` to denote the operator product (note that you can write a `CenterDot` product with the shortcut `[esc].[esc]`), `qCO` to denote the creation operator $a^\dagger$, `qDO` for the destruction operator $a$, and the built-in symbol `Ket[n]` to denote the Fock basis state $\lvert n \rangle$ (which can be inserted with `[esc]ket[esc]`).

You can of course change this notation as you like.
Here are a couple of examples of how to use the above (I here keep the full and ugly description of the operators to more clearly show what symbols are being used. Note that you can insert the `SuperDagger` with `a[ctrl+^][esc]dg[esc]`):

```
a = qDO;
SuperDagger[a] = qCO;

a\[CenterDot]Ket[2]
a\[CenterDot]a\[CenterDot]Ket[2]
a^2\[CenterDot]Ket[2]
a\[CenterDot]a\[CenterDot]a\[CenterDot]Ket[2]

a\[CenterDot]SuperDagger[a]\[CenterDot]a\[CenterDot]Ket[2]
a\[CenterDot](SuperDagger[a])^4\[CenterDot]a\[CenterDot]Ket[2]
```

[image]