# Trouble installing NCAlgebra package

Tags: packages, installation

I am interested in doing some quantum operator calculations - and tried using a quantum mathematica package as outlined in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253322/simplifying-quantum-operators-ladder-operators-with-multiple-modes?noredirect=1#comment633171_253322).

One suggestion in the comments was that I could try using the [NCAlgebra package](http://math.ucsd.edu/%7Encalg/).
But I am having trouble installing that package, and am not sure how to troubleshoot the error messages.

When I run the installation code:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NCAlgebra/NC/master/\
NCExtras/NCWebInstall.m"];
```

I get an error message that reads:
[image]

It says its a successful install dispite these error messages, but when I do as they ask and load the package it says it fails:

[image]

I'm not sure how to interpret this error message. I posted this question on the [github for the NCAlgebra package](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/issues/9), but considering that very few questions have been asked there (all unanswered), I figured it would be better to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of NCAlgebra I have explicitly added an UTF8 encoding flag during the import statements used by the installer. Hopefully this will help with these encoding issues. I do not have access to a computer with the particular encoding that you are referring to so please let me know if this is still an issue.