# grouping common powers of Bose operators

Tags: physics, algebra

I compute a product of Bose operators and turn it into normal ordering using [Boson commutation relations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95616/boson-commutation-relations/95716#95716), e.g:

```
c1 * SuperDagger[a] ** SuperDagger[a] ** a ** a + 
c2 * SuperDagger[a] ** SuperDagger[a] ** SuperDagger[a] ** a ** a ** a
```

and generally more terms. In the above `c1, c2`  are scalars while `a, SuperDagger[a]` are the Bose operators.

I can convert it to a more readable form by adding

```
/.NonCommutativeMultiply[a___] :> Infix[NonCommutativeMultiply[a],"\[InvisibleTimes]"]
```

at the end of the evaluation command, which makes the `**` symbol invisible (output is not displayed correctly here, sorry).

I would like to know whether I can make such expressions more readable by having in the output the various terms in the form `SuperDagger[a]^3 a^3`  and NOT like
`SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a a a`

Also how can I isolate specific powers e.g  `SuperDagger[a]^2  a^2` in a long expression involving many different powers of `SuperDagger[a]^n  a^n` and get their display only, e.g:

```
(3 * c1 + 5 * c0 + 7 * c6) SuperDagger[a] ** SuperDagger[a] ** a ** a
```

Collect doesn't do the trick.

Comment: True, I will change it to the original output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
expr = c1*SuperDagger[a] ** SuperDagger[a] ** a ** a + 
        c2*SuperDagger[a] ** SuperDagger[a] ** SuperDagger[a] ** a ** a ** a

ClearAll[collectPowers]
collectPowers[expr_] := 
  ReplaceRepeated[
    expr,
    {NonCommutativeMultiply[x_, x_] :> x^2,
     NonCommutativeMultiply[Power[x_, i_], x_] :> Power[x, i + 1]}
  ]


collectPowers[expr]

(* Out: c1 (SuperDagger[a])^2 ** a^2 + c2 (SuperDagger[a])^3 ** a^3 *)
```

Comment: It is useful, but in longer expressions where you have more coefficients it does not produce e.g `(c1 + 2 c2 + 5 c3^3) (SuperDagger[a])^2 ** a^2`. It produces each term separately and you have to track all terms one by one.