# normal ordering of Bose operators

Tags: physics, algebra

Suppose I have lot of product terms of Bose operators, e.g:

```
a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a]  a a a a
```

and I want to turn them into normal ordering using [Boson commutation relations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95616/boson-commutation-relations/95716#95716)

Writing each term as:

```
NCM[a, a, SuperDagger[a], SuperDagger[a], a, a, SuperDagger[a], SuperDagger[a], SuperDagger[a], SuperDagger[a],  a, a, a, a]
```

can be time consuming if you have many terms. Is there a way to work around this point? Can I somehow achieve the normal ordering by something like

```
f[a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a]  a a a a]
```

where `f` does the same thing as `NCM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[_[args___]] := NonCommutativeMultiply[args]
```

Try it out:

```
a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] \
  SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a a a a // f
```

Note that you cannot let `Times` evaluate at any time because that will re-order the arguments. So you cannot do something like:

```
expr = a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a;
f[expr]
f[Evaluate[expr]]
```

What you can do:

```
expr = Inactivate[a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a, Times];
f[Evaluate[expr]]
```

## Edit

Here's another idea:

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[expr_] := Block[{Times = NonCommutativeMultiply}, expr]
```

In this case, the following will also work:

```
expr := a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a;
f[expr]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have a question: `a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a a SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] SuperDagger[a] a a a a // f ` works fine, but I don't have to use `Inactivate`. Only when I am assigning it to `expr` I have to use `Inactivate`? Seems so

Comment: @geom Yes, that is correct. The `HoldFirst` attribute of `f` prevents `Times` from evaluating when in the first example. In the second example, `Times` would evaluate while evaluating `expr`, so the `HoldFirst` attribute cannot help you there. I do have another idea, though. Let me update the answer.