# NonCommutativeMultiply question- syntax question

Tags: symbolic, syntax, algebra

if I define `id` as:

```
id /: NonCommutativeMultiply[id, x_] := x
id /: NonCommutativeMultiply[y_, id] := y
```

then `id ** a - a ** id` gives `0`. However if:

```
NCM[x___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[x];
id /: NCM[id, x_] := x
id /: NCM[y_, id] := y
```

then `id ** a - a ** id` gives `-a ** id + id ** a`  and not `0`

I am confused as to why this happens(?)

Comment: `Attributes[TagSet]` includes `HoldAll`, so `NCM` is not expanded during the definition of the pattern and `NonCommutativeMultiply` (which you have with `**`) does not match `NCM`.

Comment: thanks. So how do I change that?

Comment: `Evaluate[NCM[...]]`, or just avoid using the abbreviation in the first place. `... /: id ** x_` and `... /: y_ ** id` should also work.

Comment: @eyorble Please post your helpful comments as an answer so that I vote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Attributes[TagSet]` includes `HoldAll`, so `NCM` is not expanded during the definition of the pattern and `NonCommutativeMultiply` (which you have with `**`) does not match `NCM`.

To avoid this, you can either expand `NCM` explicitly in the pattern by using `Evaluate`:

```
id /: Evaluate@NCM[id, x_] := x
id /: Evaluate@NCM[y_, id] := y
```

Or by avoiding the abbreviation entirely:

```
id /: id ** x_ := x
id /: y_ ** id := y
```

Alternatively, you can theoretically `Unprotect[TagSet]` and `ClearAttributes[TagSet,HoldAll]`. I am not aware of how often `TagSet` is relied upon internally, but I am quite positive that this will have unintended and likely unwanted side effects, so I can't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I found `NCM[x___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[x]` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95616/boson-commutation-relations) but I noticed that it can produce problems, hence my question