How to Compute the Hermitian Conjugate of Non-Commutative Products Symbolically in Mathematica?
I am working on symbolic quantum mechanics calculations in Mathematica, where I need to compute the Hermitian conjugate of expressions involving non-commutative operators. For instance, I have expressions like:
$$ \kappa_1 a_2 a_1^\dagger a_1^\dagger \frac{i}{2} $$
$$ \mathcal{E}_2 a_2^\dagger (-i) $$,
where:
$ a_1 $ and $ a_2 $ are annihilation operators,

$ a_1^\dagger $ and $ a_2^\dagger $ are their corresponding creation operators,
$ \kappa_1 $ and $ \mathcal{E}_2 $ are real constants,
$ i $ is the imaginary unit.

The Hermitian conjugate operation involves:

Reversing the order of non-commutative products,
Conjugating constants and the imaginary unit $ i \to -i $,
Swapping creation and annihilation operators:
$ a \to a^\dagger $ and $ a^\dagger \to a $.

For example:
$
\text{HermitianConjugate} \left( \kappa_1 a_2 a_1^\dagger a_1^\dagger \frac{i}{2} \right) = -\frac{i \kappa_1}{2} a_1 a_1 a_2^\dagger.
$
I attempted to define rules for Hermitian conjugation, but I run into recursion problems or ReplaceRepeated::rrlim errors when applying them to non-commutative multiplication (**`).
Here is the code I have so far:
(* Define Hermitian conjugate rules *)
hermitianConjugateRules = {
   a1 -> a1d, a1d -> a1,    (* Swap creation and annihilation operators *)
   a2 -> a2d, a2d -> a2, 
   I -> -I,                 (* Complex conjugate *)
   Subscript[\[Kappa], 1] -> Subscript[\[Kappa], 1],  (* Real constants *)
   Subscript[\[ScriptE], 2] -> Subscript[\[ScriptE], 2]
};

(* Attempt to define Hermitian conjugate for non-commutative products *)
HermitianConjugate[expr_] := 
  Replace[expr, 
    NonCommutativeMultiply[a_, b__] :> 
      NonCommutativeMultiply[
        HermitianConjugate[b], HermitianConjugate[a]], {1}] /. 
   hermitianConjugateRules;

(* Test terms *)
term1 = Subscript[\[Kappa], 1] ** a2 ** a1d ** a1d ** (I/2);
term2 = Subscript[\[ScriptE], 2] ** a2d ** (-I);

HermitianConjugate[term1]
HermitianConjugate[term2]

However, this approach either fails to reverse the order of products properly or triggers infinite recursion.

Question:
How can I correctly implement the Hermitian conjugate operation in Mathematica for non-commutative products like these? I want it to:

Reverse the order of operators in products,
Apply the conjugation rules consistently,
Avoid recursion errors like ReplaceRepeated::rrlim.

Any help or suggestions on a robust implementation would be greatly appreciated!

Tags:
symbolic-mathematics quantum-mechanics non-commutative pattern-matching

Avoiding recursion errors is tricky with recursively defined functions: you obviously have to make sure that there is a well-defined stopping state. Instead, I would define HermitianConjugate as follows: HermitianConjugate[a_ + b_] := HermitianConjugate[a] + HermitianConjugate[b]; HermitianConjugate[NonCommutativeMultiply[a__]] := NonCommutativeMultiply @@ Reverse@{a} /. hermitianConjugateRules. In addition, you should change I -> -I in the replacement rules with a_Complex :> Conjugate[a]. Does this work?

See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95616/7936

A few small changes guarantees that the code should work and that there will be no recursion. In addition, it will correctly take complex conjugates of complex numbers. I've taken the liberty of adjusting some of the definitions so that it works more generally with more operators, but this can easily be changed back. In addition, I've added some rules that pull the c-numbers (complex numbers) out of the NonCommutativeMultiply.
hermitianConjugateRules = {a[j_] :> a[j, d], a[j_, d] :> a[j], a_Complex :> Conjugate[a]};
HermitianConjugate[a_ + b_] := HermitianConjugate[a] + HermitianConjugate[b]
HermitianConjugate[NonCommutativeMultiply[a__]] := NonCommutativeMultiply @@ Reverse@{a} /. hermitianConjugateRules //. {NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, z_Complex, y___] :> z NonCommutativeMultiply[x, y], NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] :> x}

Then,
term1 = Subscript[k, 1] ** a[2] ** a[1, d] ** a[1, d] ** (I/2)
term2 = Subscript[e, 2] ** a[2, d] ** (-I)
term3 = (5 + 2 I) ** a[2]
HermitianConjugate[term1 + term2 + term 3]
(* Subscript[k, 1] ** a[2] ** a[1, d] ** a[1, d] ** (I/2) *)
(* Subscript[e, 2] ** a[2, d] ** (-I) *)
(* (5 + 2 I) ** a[2] *)
(* (5 - 2 I) a[2, d] + I a[2] ** Subscript[e, 2] - 1/2 I a[1] ** a[1] ** a[2, d] ** Subscript[k, 1] *)


All good it's working perfectly.

Dear @march Can you help with this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/309537/104801
