Simplifying Hermitian Conjugates and NonCommutativeMultiply Expressions in Mathematica
ClearAll[HermitianConjugate, hbar, kappa, E2, a1, a1d, a2, a2d, \
term0, term1, term2, cterm2, cterm3, H0, HI]
hbar = \[HBar];
kappa = \[Kappa];
E2 = Subscript[\[ScriptE], 2];
a1 = Subscript[a, 1];
a1d = Subsuperscript[a, 1, \[Dagger]];
a2 = Subscript[a, 2];
a2d = Subsuperscript[a, 2, \[Dagger]];
gammakj = Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], k, j];
chi = \[Chi];
term3 = I ** hbar ** E2 ** a2d;

hermitianConjugateRules = {Subscript[a, j_] :> 
    Subsuperscript[a, j, \[Dagger]], 
   Subsuperscript[a, j_, \[Dagger]] :> Subscript[a, j], 
   a_Complex :> Conjugate[a]};

HermitianConjugate[a_ + b_] := 
 HermitianConjugate[a] + HermitianConjugate[b]
HermitianConjugate[NonCommutativeMultiply[a__]] := 
  NonCommutativeMultiply @@ Reverse@{a} /. 
    hermitianConjugateRules //. {NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, 
      z_Complex, y___] :> z NonCommutativeMultiply[x, y], 
    NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] :> x};

(*Original term*)
term3 = I*hbar*E2*a2d;
rhotime1d = 
  Distribute[(-I/hbar) ** ((term3 ** \[Rho]) - (\[Rho] ** term3))];

(*Simplify to force cancellation*)
simplifiedRhoTime1D = Simplify[rhotime1d, hbar > 0]

I expected Mathematica to simplify the output by pulling out I and performing the multiplication $I * I = -1$ and canceling $\hbar$, but the result does not simplify as expected:
The result I am getting is:
(-(I/\[HBar])) ** (-\[Rho] ** (I \[HBar] Subscript[\[ScriptE], 2]
        Subsuperscript[a,2,\[Dagger]])) + (-(
    I/\[HBar])) ** (I \[HBar] Subscript[\[ScriptE], 2] Subsuperscript[
    a,2,\[Dagger]]) ** \[Rho]

How can I get Mathematica to simplify this expression properly by: Pulling $I$ outside and calculating $I * I = -1$. Canceling out $\hbar$ where appropriate.
Is there something wrong with my rules or approach? Are there additional simplification rules I need to apply?
Any advice would be appreciated!

You should try to learn from the code that's been given to you!  The rule NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, z_Complex, y___] :> z NonCommutativeMultiply[x, y] will only pull out complex numbers z, but e.g., I/\[HBar] is not in the complex numbers, because \[HBar] doesn't have a value. So you need to modify that part of the code (or add another rule) to fix the problem. Another issue is that there's no code to talke patterns of the form (c-number)*operator and pull out the c-number from the NonCommutativeMultiply.

Actually, now that I look at it, you're not actually applying any rules to your expression, because the rules are only applied when you use HermitianConjugate. You need to write a set of simplifyNCM rules that you apply to any of these expressions. Alternatively, you could adapt one of many examples here on MMA.SE. For instance.
